# SELECT statement with IF conditions and one output

Tags: sql

I am trying to map a SELECT statement into my JAVA Pojo, which has the following fields:

```
    private BigDecimal teacher_salary_by_department_one;
    private BigDecimal teacher_salary_by_department_two
    private BigDecimal teacher_salary_by_department_three
```

```
IF(job = 'teacher' AND teachers_department.id = 1, teacher_salary, 0) 
                                                                            AS teacher_salary_by_department_one,                                                    
IF(job = 'teacher' AND teachers_department.id = 2 , teacher_salary, 0) 
                                                                            AS teacher_salary_by_department_two,
IF(job = 'teacher' AND teachers_department.id = 3, teacher_salary, 0) 
                                                                            AS teacher_salary_by_department_three,
```

I know that i can use SELECT DISTINCT, but is there any other way how I can map the three fields into every object?
I am joining the "teacher_salary" table with left join by teacher_id relation.

Comment: What's the behaviour that you're getting currently? It looks to me that you are returning values for all 3 properties (you will just get a zero if the teacher is not in that particular department)

Comment: I am getting 1 result per IF, instead of mapping all the needed IF statements into one object(result)

Comment: What database are you using? You may want to rather look at using a CASE statement

Comment: @Tony MYSQL am using

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_mysql_case.asp Refactor your query to use case statements instead

Comment: This article couldn't help me a lot, sorry!
i am trying to implement it but with no success at all

Comment: Maybe it's best that you share your entire query? Then I can answer you with a code suggestion

Comment: It is included in the answer, mate!
We have an object teacher, which could have three kinds of salaries by department.
I would like to map it through this SELECT.
But it returns me three objects of Teacher with different values for every department.id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237081/discussion-between-tony-and-george-dev1222).